# Exclude conditional type helper isn't working as I understand it

Tags: typescript

I've been pouring over examples in TypeScript trying to understand how exactly the `Exclude` conditional type helper works *on its own*.

As defined by the TypeScript docs:

> Exclude – Exclude from T those types that are assignable to U.

As defined in the library:

```
/**
 * Exclude from T those types that are assignable to U
 */
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
```

I've seen a lot of incorrect blog posts from users and I've tried a lot of code like the following:

```
type User = {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   phone: number;
   isAdmin: boolean;
};
// Doesn't work below as standardUser still has all properties
type standardUser = Exclude<User, 'isAdmin'>;
```

What I'm hoping to see is that `standardUser` is a `type` that is defined but doesn't have the `isAdmin` property. The result is the `type standardUser` still has *all* the same properties and is no different. I've also used an `interface` instead of the `type` alias and it exhibits the same behavior.

Looking at the [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html), I see (2) examples provided (and of course using literals and primitives which are theoretical and aren't translating well at all.

```
type T00 = Exclude<"a" | "b" | "c" | "d", "a" | "c" | "f">;  // "b" | "d"
type T02 = Exclude<string | number | (() => void), Function>;  // string | number
```

They both work, but I'm not translating to real-world applications here. I then thought as mentioned in the definition that it *excludes types assignable to the other* so then I tried this:

```
type User = {
   id: string;
   isAdmin: boolean;
};
// Doesn't work below as standardUser still has all properties
type standardUser = Exclude<User, boolean>;
```

Again I was hoping to see that `standardUser` was defined as a type with only `id` as the `boolean` type should have been excluded. Again my understanding of this raw helper is off.

I also tried with an `enum` and this didn't subtract any values either and the new type remains the same with all available values:

```
enum Fruits {
   apple,
   pear,
   bananna      
}
// Doesn't work below as redFruit still has all values
type redFruit = Exclude<fruits, 'pear' | 'bananna'>;
```

I'm also well aware of using `Exclude` via the `keyOf` in combination with `Pick` to create an `Omit` type and this ultimately works nicely with my 1st example above to yield a type with the subtracted properties expected:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

OK I get using `Exclude` via the `keyof T` will create a shortlist of the keys desired and `Pick` does the rest. However, I still really want to understand a non-theoretical use case example for the `Exclude` helper and how it works on its own. To me if `Exclude` worked as I think it does, I wouldn't need to create the `Omit` type. Those contrived examples from the docs might be great for 2 lists of string literals, but I'd like to know how `Exclude` works in conjunction with an `interface` or `type` please? Or am I misunderstanding it's usage and it should always be used in conjuntion with `keyof?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type User = {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   phone: number;
   isAdmin: boolean;
};

// Doesn't work below as standardUser still has all properties
type standardUser = Exclude<User, 'isAdmin'>;
```

`Exclude` works on types. From your example, it seems like you want `Exclude` to work not on types, but on properties - `'isAdmin'` is a property name, not a type in your example.

> However, I still really want to understand a non-theoretical use case example for the Exclude helper and how it works on its own. To me if Exclude worked as I think it does, I wouldn't need to create the Omit type.

Unfortunately it does not work as you think it does. As it is, `Exclude` is not theoretical, but rather low-level building block which allows you to construct the types that you need, like `Omit`. Without using intermediate type like `Omit`, you can get the desired type from `User` in this way:

```
type standardUser = { [k in Exclude<keyof User, 'isAdmin'>]: User[k] };
```

Here's the same type constructed step-by-step:

```
type Step1 = keyof User; // get union type of User keys 
// type Step1 = "id" | "name" | "phone" | "isAdmin"

type Step2 = Exclude<Step1, 'isAdmin'>;  // remove "isAdmin" from union type
// type Step2 = "id" | "name" | "phone"

type Step3 = { [k in Step2]: User[k] }; // mapped type
// see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types 
// same as user, but without 'isAdmin' key 
// type Step3 = { id: string; name: string; phone: number; }
```

> but I'd like to know how Exclude works in conjunction with an interface or type

In general, it's helpful to think of types in terms of sets of all possible values. For example, the `User` type can be viewed as a set of all objects which have all 4 properties: 'id', 'name', 'phone', 'isAdmin', each with appropriate type. So essentially it's the same as an intersection of 4 types:

```
{id: string} & {name: string} & {phone: string} & {isAdmin: boolean}
```

If you want to drop `isAdmin` property, you actually are expanding the set of objects that conform to the new type - to conform, object now must have only 3 properties, not all 4. In other words, the set of "normal" users is bigger than the set of "admin" users. So `Exclude`, which "shrinks" the type, is not directly helpful here. `Exclude` works best on union types, of which `keyof` is the most often used.